# Sklearn Random Forest Regressor Prediction Problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a problem when predicting with a random forest Regressor. I trained and save the learned model then, I have a test data set to predict on, that includes 100,000 rows.

For one row, it gives 47 as prediction result. I gave exactly the same row in a file but only that one row not the others. It predicts the result as 33.

I can't change the result no matter what I change in data columns.
I couldn't find any solution to this problem, any idea?

Algorithm :

```
algorithm = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20,  random_state=0) 
scale_features_std = StandardScaler()
data_X = scale_features_std.fit_transform(data_X)
algorithm.fit(data_X, data_Y)
joblib.dump(algorithm, fileName) #save the model for further use.
```

Comment: Are you fitting the model with the same data for both cases? Could you share a bit more code please? (Mostly the fitting and prediction part). And please comment here when you did so I can get the notification and check the question again, thanks.

Comment: I dont know how to explain more :( , i use exactly the same model because i saved it. @CeliusStingher

Comment: Are you using `train_test_split()` before to assign `data_X` and `data_Y`? Are you sure the prediction row 33 actually belongs to the row 33 of the original dataframe?

Comment: no,  i dont ,  i give the original dataset to the algorithm :/ @CeliusStingher

Comment: The sequence of events from your code : Fit Random Forest, then scale the features. We must first scale features and then fit the model, but for a tree based algorithm scaling may not be needed.  Also, in the given snippet, test data does not figure. Any way you can provide additional code?

Comment: Definitely it makes sense if you are fitting the scaling in a dataset and then fitting it on another dataset (the only row) you will provide different input-values to your model, making it understable why you are getting different outputs (predictions).

Comment: Thank you a lot @CeliusStingher and achow, i deleted the scale part. Then it returns the same prediction value :)

Comment: If it improves the performance of the model, you don't need to remove, but apply it before training the model and then use the same scaler for your values (do not fit on new data, just like you do with your model!)